# Delete all files from TortoiseSVN working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows.

I want to delete all files from all folders, so I can import a new source tree to find the differences including deleted files. (Quite similar to updating a vendor branch.)

What is the easiest method to do this?

Comment: If I understood fine you're trying to see differences between two branches, correct?

Comment: Correct, if you call the second source tree a "branch" although it's not under version control.

Comment: And what about zip the second branch, and unzip over the current copy? I guess that you need to manage deleted files also, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is not too painful. Search for all files in the folder (with a *), then delete all .svn folders (but only move them to recycle bin). then delete the remaining files (for real). Restore the .svn folders from the recycle bin...

Edit: If you have to do it often, you probably should write some script that does the job...

Comment: Interesting method but seems to work. Thanks. :) I hope the recycle bin is a safe (deterministic) place. I'll probably write a script later that even deals with deleted folders.